# Amazon S3 Prawn PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

upon adding an image to my prawn document and trying to pull that image from Amazon S3 storage I get the following error

```
ArgumentError (http://s3.amazonaws.com/briefbucket/photos/2/small/259823_1583726693707_1851950185_973122_7126850_n.jpg?1326839482 not found):
```

however i looked in my storage folder, the jpg is there. I noticed that the ending file name in prawn is "jpg?1326839482"?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Alright, I had the same issue today. Now: 
I'm using Amazon S3 and loading images uploaded by users. Solution as follows:

```
if @user.avatar? #in case user didn't upload anything
  image open("#{ @user.avatar(:small).to_s.sub!(/\?.+\Z/, '') }")
end
```

Following

```
.to_s.sub!(/\?.+\Z/, '')
```

is used the get rid of all stuff after "?"

Before I have moved to amazon i was not using "open" which was causing the issue.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: **Rock on!** Worked like a charm.  Thanks.  I was unable to get it working before with this: `image "#{Prawn::DATADIR}/..`    or this type of thing: `image open("@user.avatar.url(:medium)").read`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand, but I think you need to URL encode your file name (See [encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)).

So your encoded file would be something like:

```
http://s3.amazonaws.com/briefbucket/photos/2/small/259823_1583726693707_1851950185_973122_7126850_n.jpg%3F1326839482
```

The `?` character is used to designate the beginning of the search path.

Comment: do you have any suggestions on how I would encode the request to pull that image into the pdf?

Comment: my larger question is why is your image file name 259823_1583726693707_1851950185_973122_7126850_n.jpg?1326839482.

Comment: in my bucket on amazon S3 my filename is 259823_1583726693707_1851950185_973122_7126850_n.jpg that is what amazon stores it as???

Comment: where would you recommend to start looking to solve this problem?

Comment: did anyone come up with a solution to this issue?